# How to redirect in nginx based on cookie header with alias?

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a webserver that i want to configure like, using cookie.lua by cloudfare.

```
local key = "123"
local accessKey, err = cookie:get("access-key")
if accessKey == key then
  ngx.var.proxy = "my_remote_server"
else 
  alias a static location
end
```

My problem is that i think there is a lua variable that support proxy_pass which means ngx.var.proxy, but there is no equivalent in alias to a static location.
So is there an example config that can solve my problem? thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly.

If you want to redirect to another route based on a cookie (or any Lua condition, really) you can use [`ngx.exec`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ngxexec), which does an internal redirect; meaning the client will receive a reply as if they navigated to that new URI, but it all happens server-side so the client doesn't get redirected and still sees the old URI in the browser.

I don't know if this is 100% equivalent to using alias, but you can always combine it with [`ngx.var.VARIABLE`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ngxvarvariable) and another route that has an actual `alias` directive making use of a `$VARIABLE`.